# how indicate the company that made the lowest offer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel sheet, where there are three companies with the related offers. With a formula, I calculate the lowest offer.

How can I indicate in another cell, the name of the company that made the lowest offer?

[image: my excel sheet]

Comment: What if there's a tie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This formula could do the job:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$C$1;0;MATCH(MIN($A2:$C2);$A2:$C2;0))
```

It retrieves the index of a column containing the minimum,
and uses it to select the column header.
`$A2:$C2` is the range containing the values and `$A$1:$C$1` is the headers.

(Note: In case where Excel indicates a syntax error in the formula,
try using commas instead of semicolons.)

References:

- [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd)
- [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)

Comment: Can you explain how this works? Good answers explain and teach.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: Done as requested.

Comment: @harrymc the formula contains an error https://imgur.com/AKSAGZe

Comment: Mine too now gives an error. It seems like it insists on ';' as separator. Try the new formula.

Comment: Comma vs. semicolon as a parameter delimiter is a locale-based difference.  You need to use the delimiter dictated by your locale.

Comment: @fixer1234: Thanks. I was wondering why comma worked sometime ago but now only semicolon works. One more "brilliant" idea from the Office team.

Comment: @harrymc now works. it was enough to change only the name of the functions. "index" is "indice" in Italy. match is "confronta" in Italy

Comment: Fantastic: A formula that works in one location may not work in another. Separators change, keywords change. Bravo Microsoft.

Answer (score -1):

**These methods will fix the issue:**

[image]

**My approach is little different to solve the 
  issue:**

- **Method 1,** finds lowest in entire Data Range 
  instead to find Row by Row.

*Considering Data in `D1:F4`:*

- Formula in Cell `H2` to find lowest value 
  `=MIN(D2:F4)`.
- Use this Array Formula in Cell `J2` to find the 
  Company.

  `{=INDEX($D$1:$F$1,,SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$F$4=H2)*(COLUMN($D$2:$F$4)-COLUMN($C$1))))}`

**N.B.** Finish the Formula with 
         **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

- **Method 2**, finds multiple Company names, in 
  case if more than one Company has lowest bid.

*Considering Data in `D8:F11`:*

- Formula in Cell `G9` to  find lowest in Range.
- Enter this Array Formula in Cell `H9`, finish 
  with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**, fill Right then 
  Down.

  `{=IF(COLUMNS($H9:H9)>COUNTIF($D9:$F9,$G$9),"",INDEX($8:$8,SMALL(IF($D9:$F9=$G$9,COLUMN($D9:$F9)),COLUMNS($H9:H9))))}`

**Adjust Cell & Row references in the Formula as needed.**

Comment: Maybe I did not say it clear enough.  I need to find the lowest price and therefore also the company with the lowest price, but for each row.

Comment: @nicovon, that's the reason I've written that my approach is different,, find Minimum in Row and related Company is rather easier but not a popular practice. Since I've tried to show how to find the lowest bidder & the Company and in case of Duplicate/Tie also, which is very common,, and this point has been raised by other readers also,, one is #Fixer1234  ☺